# Arithmetic functions on list elements in a data frame column

Tags: r, dataframe, list, apply

One of the columns in my data frame is a list. I would like to add a numerical value to each number in the list but the length of the result does not match the original data frame because some lists have several elements.

Here is an example of the data

```
test <-data.frame("pep_index" = seq(1,6,1), "pep_start"=c(387,8464,33,57,100,7543), "pep_var_mod_pos"=c("000200020002000","00020000","2000000","00000000000","00220000000","000000002"))
test$pep_var_mod_index <- gregexec(pattern="2", test$pep_var_mod_pos)
test$pep_var_mod_index[test$pep_var_mod_index=="-1"] <- NA

head(test)
#   pep_index pep_start pep_var_mod_pos pep_var_mod_index
# 1         1       387 000200020002000          4, 8, 12
# 2         2      8464        00020000                 4
# 3         3        33         2000000                 1
# 4         4        57     00000000000                NA
# 5         5       100     00220000000              3, 4
# 6         6      7543       000000002                 9
''''

I have tried apply and ddply functions, e.g.


library(plyr)
test$pep_var_mod_res <- ddply(test, c("pep_index"), function(x) unlist(x$pep_var_mod_index) + x$pep_start )
```

But I do not get my desired outcome, which is:

```
#  pep_index pep_start pep_var_mod_pos pep_var_mod_index pep_var_mod_res
# 1         1       387 000200020002000          4, 8, 12   391, 395, 399
# 2         2      8464        00020000                 4            8468
# 3         3        33         2000000                 1              34
# 4         4        57     00000000000                NA              NA
# 5         5       100     00220000000              3, 4        103, 104
# 6         6      7543       000000002                 9            7552
```

Comment: Why are there backslashes in your code? This is not valid R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `mapply` or similar to iterate in parallel over `pep_var_mod_index` and `pep_start`.

```
test$pep_var_mod_res = with(test, mapply("+", pep_start, pep_var_mod_index))

test                            
#   pep_index pep_start pep_var_mod_pos pep_var_mod_index pep_var_mod_res
# 1         1       387 000200020002000          4, 8, 12   391, 395, 399
# 2         2      8464        00020000                 4            8468
# 3         3        33         2000000                 1              34
# 4         4        57     00000000000                NA              NA
# 5         5       100     00220000000              3, 4        103, 104
# 6         6      7543       000000002                 9            7552
```